# How to extract part of the properties' keys of an object as a union type?

Tags: typescript, object, properties, union-types

In Typescript, I'd like to do the following:

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsgmgfQPICEBSBRAwgFSgXigG8AoKKAMwHsqBBALigGdgAnASwDsBzAGjMo0UjFhx78AviRKhIUAMpIYGBAAUASklXyCUDAA82AQwDGwADwBrCCCoVYiVJly8oAImp03UAD7vPKN5+HjRYbgB8QA)

```
type MY_OBJECT = {
  fooA: string,
  fooB: string,
  fooD: string,
  fooE: string,
  fooF: string
}

type SOME_PROPS = Extract<keyof MY_OBJECT, "fooA" | "fooB" | "fooC">
```

I'd like Typescript to "know" that there's no `"fooC"` available on `keyof MY_OBJECT` and warn me about that.

In other words, I'd like to extract part of the properties of an object and a union type and I'd like to keep it all strongly typed.

For example, if I ever change `fooA` to `fooAAA` on `MY_OBJECT`, I'd like to know immediately that I need to fix something on that `Extract<>` type, since `fooA` would no longer exist.

Is it possible?

**My use case:** I have a Redux action that is supposed to update some of the properties of a specific object. So I'll be using that union type (composed by the selected property names) to type my action and make sure that the action receive only the allowed names.

```
type MY_OBJECT = {
  fooA: string,
  fooB: string,
  fooD: string,
  fooE: string,
  fooF: string
}

type SOME_PROPS = Extract<keyof MY_OBJECT, "fooA" | "fooB">
type UPDATE_SOME_PROPS  = PayloadAction<{ name: SOME_PROPS , value: SOME_VALUE }>
```

Comment: Are you looking for [something like this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ93rm)?  I'm a bit confused about why you're using `Extract` at all.  I'm also confused why you don't just use `keyof MY_OBJECT` instead of building `SOME_PROPS` and then checking it later, so a little bit more about the use case would help make this a [mcve].  If my above code link works for you, I'll write up an answer.  Otherwise, please elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I forgot to mention where I would be using that. I'll add it to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I've ended up doing:

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsgmgfQPICEBSBRAwgFSgXigG8AoKKAMwHsqBBALigGdgAnASwDsBzAGjMo0UjFhx79y1KgBERbLnwFSMcsYsk0AYqoUkAviRKhIUAMpIYGBAAUASkmumCUANYQQVClGvsAxi4AeeGR0bBxeKAAiKVpIqAAfKKkUSIA+I3Boc0sbe0cEHAxTPEI3Dy8ffyDEVExcCOiaWISkoTjExqosNKA)

I'm using `keyof Pick<>`. This way you get intellisense for the extracted properties.

```
type MY_OBJECT = {
  fooA: string,
  fooB: string,
  fooD: string,
  fooE: string,
  fooF: string
}

type SOME_PROPS = keyof Pick<MY_OBJECT, "fooA" | "fooB">
type SOME_PROPS_TEST = keyof Pick<MY_OBJECT, "fooA" | "fooB" | "fooC">

type SOME_PROPS = keyof Pick<MY_OBJECT, "fooA" | "fooB">                   // WORKS
type SOME_PROPS_TEST = keyof Pick<MY_OBJECT, "fooA" | "fooB" | "fooC">     // TRIGGERS ERROR
```

Comment: can you explain why you need this instead of `type SOME_PROPS = keyof MY_OBJECT`?  I still feel like we're missing a [mcve] that motivates such type manipulation

Comment: Does the `MY_OBJECT` have more properties defined on it, and you are only wanting a subset of the properties?

Comment: Yes. That's it. The object has more properties. And I just want a subset of them.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks. I've added my use case to the question. Sorry for the confusion I've caused.